# Install Ubuntu on UEFI without Windows or Boot Loader

Tags: system-installation, windows-8, uefi, bootloader, grub-efi

I have a Gateway netbook that has already been fully wiped with nothing on the hard drive. There is no Legacy option in bios and the only thing I can boot from the USB is a Gparted disk utilizing Grub/EFI loader in which I can partition the drive. But nothing else will boot from USB including Boot Repair, ReFINd, multiple Linux Live CDs, or Super Grub disks. Ubuntu installation disks won't show up, there is no boot loader on the hard drive and I don't know how to get anything installed. It seems to be a UEFI motherboard PC without a bios boot option. All the articles I am coming across deal with dual boots on EFI, or Windows 8 machines. Mine was a Windows 8 preinstalled machine that no longer has Windows on it. Any guidance on installing a boot loader and Ubuntu would be much appreciated.

Comment: Part of the problem might be Secure Boot. Look for an option to disable it in your firmware. Details vary greatly from one machine to another, though, so I can't give you precise details. See [here](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/secureboot.html#disable) for a few samples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up solving this issue. I found out that even though the netbook was a newer model it was actually 32 bit. Therefore none of the 64 bit disk images would boot because they only contained 64 bit EFI drivers. I ended up...

1. Downloading a 32 bit version of Linux Mint (which didn't have EFI support).
2. I took the EFI folder from Gparted boot disk (which also had 32 bit EFI drivers) and copied it to the Linux Mint USB. This explains why only the Gparted disk would boot when others wouldn't.

Booted instantly, installed successfully, and is running like a charm. Loving Linux Mint 17!!!

Comment: Oh my god, what an exotic hardware haha

Answer (score 2):

There is much variation in hardware, but I was able to boot to an Ubuntu 14.04 live USB in UEFI / Secure Boot mode by doing the following:

1) Download the Ubuntu distro you want. **It must be the 64 bit version.**

2) Install the distro to USB stick using PendriveLinux.com's [Universal USB Installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/).

3) Power off the PC, insert the USB stick, and power on.

4) Hold down the appropriate key to enter the BIOS.

5) Change the boot order so that the USB stick is first

**Note, unlike regular BIOSes I am used to, you have to do this step EVERY TIME YOU WANT TO BOOT OFF USB.  The boot order changes are not persistent!  In fact, my UEFI BIOS does not even offer me this choice unless a UEFI bootable USB stick is currently inserted**  Until I figured this out, I was in the same situation as you, I could not get it to boot off USB at all.

6) Exit the BIOS "saving" your changes and allow the boot to complete.

Comment: There is no additional tool necessary to "install" to content from the ISO on to the USB stick, just mount the file or open it with a tool like 7z to copy or extract the files to the root of the USB stick. Good point though that you need the amd64 version to boot UEFI.

Comment: I'm sure you are correct; I was merely recounting what worked for me, so not everything I list may be necessary.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I ended up solving this issue by doing what I explained below.

Comment: There is either BIOS or UEFI. No UEFI BIOS.  So I guess you are talking about UEFI, right? Just to avoid some confusion.